# sort a collection based on multiple fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've a requirement where I need to sort the collection based on different fields. Below is my db entry

```
db.requests.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5caf805f50ca58361589924b"),"type" : "adhoc",  "immediate" : false, "place": "london"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c947e37015bfe78a80e5349"),"type" : "adhoc",  "immediate" : true, "place": "tokoy" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9481fa015bfe78a80e534d"),"type" : "periodic",  "immediate" : false , "place": "bangalore"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c94ae95015bfe78a80e5363"),"type" : "adhoc",  "immediate" : true, "place": "lanka"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c875a96015bfe7b5e772ea3"),"type" : "adhoc",  "immediate" : false, "place": "jakarta"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9481fa015bfe78a80e534d"),"type" : "periodic",  "immediate" : false , "place": "europe"}
```

considering
       If "type" is "adhoc" then "immediate" can be either "true" or "false". 
       If "type" is "periodic" then "immediate" will always be "false"

I just want to have result in the below order:

1. all entries with "immediate" : "true"
2. all entries with "type": "adhoc" and "immediate": "false"
3. all entries with "type":"periodic"

Result should be like:

```
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5c947e37015bfe78a80e5349"),"type" : "adhoc",  "immediate" : true, "place": "tokoy" }
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5c94ae95015bfe78a80e5363"),"type" : "adhoc",  "immediate" : true, "place": "lanka"}
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5caf805f50ca58361589924b"),"type" : "adhoc",  "immediate" : false, "place": "london"}
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5c875a96015bfe7b5e772ea3"),"type" : "adhoc",  "immediate" : false, "place": "jakarta"}
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5c9481fa015bfe78a80e534d"),"type" : "periodic",  "immediate" : false , "place": "bangalore"}
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5c9481fa015bfe78a80e534d"),"type" : "periodic",  "immediate" : false , "place": "europe"}
```